# How to create an XML document from xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xsd, schema

I need to transform my domain object into an xml document for a third party data exchange.

I have a mapping document with the location of the data from my domain and an xpath of where this data exports into the xml document.

What I am looking to do is build an engine that will read this mapping file pull the data out of my domain object and build the proper xml document.

My current difficulty is while taking the xpaths to build I need to ensure that the xml sequences are placed in the correct order.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

** I am trying to avoid bringing in classes representing xml documents in to my code base.  This way we can add a new export with out recompiling the project.

Comment: I don't see what XPath has to do with this. You simply use xsd.exe and it generates a schema for the given class. You need to make your class serializable, and you can use the standard .NET XmlSerializer class to serialize any instance of your class into XML.

Comment: In most cases it's because I have the xpath and 600+ data points to map.  xpath tells me where to put my domain data point in the xml.

Comment: @_Aaron Fischer: Sorry, but it is impossible from your question and your comments to understand what is it you want. Try to be more specific. A small, but complete example of any input documents and the exact output wanted, will help tremendously.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, I tried to clean up my question maybe that will help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest something a little different than what you're asking, because I've found xpath a bit cumbersome and when I first started using LINQ to XML it was a mini revolution of happiness within me.

One of the advantages here is that if you ever decide you want to serialize differently, there's little code change, you simply need to find a Linq to (Json, SQL, etc) library (of which there are many, and things like SQL are provided by Microsoft) and make very minor code changes.

Check out [Linq to Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) on msdn.

If you think that you might be interested in this, or more about Linq, I found the book *Linq in Action* to be a very good book to get the basics down.

Comment: +1 I'll second that. XPath is a pain. I wonder if LINQ is an option for OP though...

Comment: How would linq to xml help me form a valid xml document? And keep my elements in the proper sequence order?

Comment: @Aaron: The smarmy answer there is "very easily". Here's [another link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Construction-Samples-231a06cb) that has a short example that may be helpful. I find the Linq To Xml much easier to read, write, and maintain than other XML libraries.

Comment: @Aaron: And [here is another link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2007/02/20/xlinq-create-xml-from-object-using-linq.aspx) that may be even better.

Comment: @kevek I don't want to know about the xml structure I output.  To use linq to xml I would need to hand code the export, and I would have to know what element should be first in a sequence and which second.

Comment: I agree with @Aaron - linq to xml does not address the problem - it's simply another way to hand-crank xml.

Comment: Xpath may be a pain but it's performant for large xml files as it can be applied to a stream. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950778.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It would be easiest for you generate type libraries from the contracts exposed on the various interfaces you need to generate messages for. You can do this with xsd.exe or svcutil.exe for wcf endpoints.

Then if you need to generate a xml instance for a specific interface you simply popluate an instance of the type for the interface and use XmlSerializer.Serialize() to serialize an instance message for that interface.

This has the benefits:

1. that your xml instances will conform to the endpoint schemas
2. you do not need to hand-crank the xml out each time

If you want me to explain any of the steps in more detail let me know via a comment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was hoping to not need a formal class, but it's looking to be the simplest way to structure content.

Comment: At least there is low overhead on creating and maintaining the classes because they are generated. I can't think of a way to generate xml without some formal model which represents the desired xml first.